# How to catch errors in web3.py

Tags: solidity, web3.py, error

How can I catch revert or out of gas errors in web3.py?
I'd like to call a function through web3.py and in case it gets reverted I'd like to try it again after a couple of seconds.

Comment: How about `try`/`except AssertionError`???